# Load XML via MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, xml, stored-procedures

I have run a SQL statement in MySQL which has been executed successfully. I now want to run this as a stored procedure which will eventually be executed via Python (which I am using to scrape from the website initially).

The SQL statement runs, but I am getting the following error with the stored procedure:

```
ERROR 1314: LOAD XML is not allowed in stored procedures
```

The SQL statment is bascially:

```
Load XML Local Infile 'myfile.XML' into table MyTable rows identified by '<DATAROW>'
```

Am I missing something very basic with MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are probably using a version wich is up to 5.0.7

As from documentation: **this was not more allowed since version 5.0.7**

Please check this http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14977

Comment: yikes, I saw this issue but I thought that it would have been resolved in the last 7.5 years. Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: @user1966593 not that i'm aware about, sorry about that. If the answer was helpfull please accept it for help people in the future with similar problems